# Why is lasso not strictly convex

Tags: optimization

I know a nonmonotonic convex function which attains its minimum value at a unique point only is strictly convex. I didn't get how lasso is not strictly convex. For eg if I consider two dimensional case.

$||x||_1$ attains its minimum value at (0,0) which is unique

Comment: Why do you believe your first sentence is true? As an antidote, try $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ and $g(x) = e^x$, both defined on $\mathbb R$. One has no minimum at all and the other has a unique one. Which is which? One is strictly convex and the other is not convex at all. Which is which?

Comment: @cardinal. I have changed the question. In your case the first one is not convex at all even it has a unique minimum and the second one is strictly convex but has no minimum(or infinity). I have modified the question.

Comment: $f(x) = |x|$ has a unique minimum, as you've pointed out. It is not strictly convex. So your (new) first sentence also needs modification. :-) One candidate: A nonmonotonic strictly convex function has a unique minimum.

Comment: @cardinal. That's my original question. Why is $|x|$ not strictly convex

Comment: Do you know the definition of 'strictly convex'?

Comment: @Glen_b. I think I got it

Comment: @Glen_b. If I take any points lets say 0 and 1, and another point 0.5 in between them. The average of the functional value f(0) and f(1) is equal to the functional value at 0.5. so not strictly convex. I had this definition in my mind, that it has a unique minimizer, is it wrong then? I guess I had the wrong definition. Just because a function has unique minimum, it isn't strictly convex

Comment: Sorry, I can't work out which of several possible things on this page is being referred to by 'it' there -- you thought that that what in particular had a unique minimizer?

Comment: @Glen_b. I thought that a strictly convex function is a convex function which has a unique minimizer. I am saying this was the wrong definition

Comment: @cardinal's example of $e^x$ already showed you that a strictly convex function needn't have a unique minimizer.

Comment: @Glen_b. Yeah, I got it now. Come on guys, I am just a beginner so don't be hard on me :)

Comment: My apologies; I didn't intend to make you feel I was being harsh.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that a strictly convex function is a convex function which has a unique minimizer. I am saying this was the wrong definition.

Indeed, this was quite wrong, and the source of confusion here. What is true is that strict convexity is related to uniqueness of minimizer: if a strictly convex function attains its minimum, then it does so at exactly one point. However, having unique minimizer does not imply strict convexity, or any convexity at all.

It's important to remember that there are **two different notions** of strict convexity. Namely, we have:

1. Strictly convex functions: $u(ta+(1-t)b)<tu(a)+(1-t)u(b)$ for $0<t<1$
2. Strictly convex norms: $\|ta+(1-t)b\|<t\|a\|+(1-t)\|b\|$ for $0<t<1$, unless $a$ and $b$ are parallel vectors.

A norm can  *never* be strictly convex function in the sense of definition 1, because for any nonzero vector $x$ we have $$\|2x\|=\frac12({\|x\|+\|3x\|}),\quad \text{where }\ 2x=\frac12(x+3x)$$
This is why the definition of a strictly convex *norm* requires non-parallel vectors. But $\|\cdot\|_1$ fails the second definition too: for example, 
$$\|e_1+e_2\|=\frac12({\|2e_1\|+\|2e_2\|}),\quad \text{where }\ e_1+e_2=\frac12(2e_1+2e_2)$$
and $e_1,e_2$ are standard basis vectors.